# Table column doesn't want get the width from CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I have a table with a nested table. I want to align each column with the nested column, so it looks the same width, as well both are responsive table's.

I can't get around the size for both table with independent id's, but as reference i put 11:00 in 2 cells, they should basically align in display.

I try to control it via CSS and it should be like this.

I have a snippet below, this includes bootstrap 4 css.

```css
/* Below is the Schedule Part for the Reservation Manager */

#reservationManagerScrolltbody {
  height: 10em;
  /* Just for the demo          */
  overflow-y: auto;
  /* Trigger vertical scroll    */
  overflow-x: auto;
  /* Trigger horizontal scroll    */
  width: 100px;
}

#table2 td+td {
  border-left: 2px solid #F5F5F5;
}

#table2 th+th,
th,
td {
  border-left: 2px solid #F5F5F5;
  font-size: 0.75vw;
  width: 50px;
}

#waiterStationTableinfo td+td,
th {
  border-left: 1px solid #F5F5F5;
}

.wstinfo {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- right container -->
<div id="right">
  <h6 style="font-size:1vw; ">Search by any table</h6>
  <input style="margin-top:0.5em margin-bottom: 0.5em;" class="form-control" type="text" id="reservationManagerListTableNumberInput" placeholder="Search for any table.. ">
  <table class="table table-responsive table-sm table-hover" style="margin-top:0.5em;" id="table2">
    <thead class="header">
      <tr>
        <!-- if checkbox is checked, clone reservation subjects to the whole table row  -->
        <th class="wstinfo">
          <input id="week" type="checkbox" title="Preassign Table by drag and drop Reservation in each slot" checked/>
          <input id="report" type="checkbox" title="Show Assignment report" />

        </th>
        <th class="wstinfo">1</th>
        <th class="wstinfo">1</th>
        <th class="wstinfo">1</th>
        <th class="redips-mark dark">11:00</th>
        <th class="redips-mark dark">11:30</th>
        <th class="redips-mark dark">12:00</th>
        <th class="redips-mark dark">12:30</th>
        <th class="redips-mark dark">13:00</th>
        <th class="redips-mark dark">13:30</th>
        <th class="redips-mark dark">14:00</th>
        <th class="redips-mark dark">14:30</th>
        <th class="redips-mark dark">17:00</th>
        <th class="redips-mark dark">17:30</th>
        <th class="redips-mark dark">18:00</th>
        <th class="redips-mark dark">18:30</th>
        <th class="redips-mark dark">19:00</th>
        <th class="redips-mark dark">19:30</th>
        <th class="redips-mark dark">20:00</th>
        <th class="redips-mark dark">20:30</th>
        <th class="redips-mark dark">21:00</th>
        <th class="redips-mark dark">21:30</th>
        <th class="redips-mark dark">22:00</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="reservationManagerScrolltbody">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="24" class="reservationManagerTableType">
          <table class="table table-sm waiterStationTableinfo">

            <thead class="header">
              <tr>
                <th class="wstinfo">TN</th>
                <th class="wstinfo">TT</th>
                <th class="wstinfo">RA</th>
                <th class="wstinfo">GA</th>
                <th colspan="20" style="text-align:center;"> Waiterstation 1</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>116</td>
                <td>2 TOP</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>11:00</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>22:00</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>116</td>
                <td>2 TOP</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>6</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>116</td>
                <td>2 TOP</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>6</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>116</td>
                <td>4 TOP</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>6</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="24" class="reservationManagerTableType">
          <table class="table table-sm waiterStationTableinfo">

            <thead class="header">
              <tr>
                <th class="wstinfo">TN</th>
                <th class="wstinfo">TT</th>
                <th class="wstinfo">RA</th>
                <th class="wstinfo">GA</th>
                <th colspan="20" style="text-align:center;"> Waiterstation 1</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>154</td>
                <td>2 TOP</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>6</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>116</td>
                <td>2 TOP</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>6</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>116</td>
                <td>2 TOP</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>6</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>116</td>
                <td>2 TOP</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>6</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<!-- right container -->
```

Comment: you haven't given your width a unit type (ie px rem vw etc), also why explicitly name `#table2 th+th` when you style all th with the same style?  Another thing to consider is nested tables in a cell with a colspan of 20?  This looks like you shouldn't be using tables

Comment: Shouldn't the colspan of the `td` containing the nested tables be a least 22?

Comment: I have updated the snippet with correct width unit and colspan value. Thanks for the hints. @ZimSystem it should be 24.